# How to use dplyr to inner_join Date values in R with DateTime values in an SQL database?

Tags: sql, r, database, dplyr

I am currently trying to perform an inner join between a local table in R and a table in an SQL database. The catch is that the SQL database has records with a DateTime column, while my local table only has Date values and I am trying to perform this join without including the Time component.

(Note that I am familiar with R, but have only a basic understanding of SQL)

The following code is what I have tried, and the error that it's giving me:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "ecNAQUAop")

NAQUA_tbl <- dplyr::tbl(con, dbplyr::in_schema("data", "table1"))

df.test <- NAQUA_tbl %>%
  mutate(Convert(Date, SampleDateTime)) %>%
  inner_join(local(join_tbl), by = c("SampleDateTime", "Location", "Variable"), copy = T) %>%
  collect()

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

I can't tell whether it's my local table or the database table that the error is referring to.

What function can I use in the R code to convert the DateTime in the SQL database to a Date format before the inner_join?

Comment: My R is weak.  Where are you bringing in the data from SQL Server?  Is that NAQUA_tbl?

Comment: @dougp Oops, I left out the line `NAQUA_tbl <- dplyr::tbl(con, dbplyr::in_schema("data", "table1"))` which makes the connection to my data table in SQL. I've edited the question

Comment: SQL has a `varchar` datatype and R does not, so the error message is referring to your database table.

Comment: There appears to be a bunch of information missing or incorrect in the original post.  The error message appears to come from SQL Server, but I can't tell why based on the information provided.  For some reason SQL server is trying to convert a varchar to a datetime, but one or more of the values are not compatible.  But the problem description states that the data is date time in the source.  Maybe the database table (table1?) is not really a table, but a view that is not functioning correctly.

Comment: Could you share the output of  `head(NAQUA_tbl$SampleDateTime)`?